# How to prefill user field in custom aspx form?

Tags: user-controls, user-profile-property, user-accounts

I have a task to create SP2010 inventory request system based on VS2010. The idea is the requestor creates a request, which contains inventory information and approvers. Approvers is the user field that must contain several managers of the requestor, as you understand it should be dynamic field, where the user must select the appropriate one as an approver. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom entity picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc889345%28office.12%29.aspx). It is very big tutorial to provide it in this answer. The main steps:

1. Create custom field
2. Create class which is inherited from EntityEditorWithPicker
3. Create class which is inherited from PickerDialog
4. Create class which is inherited from SimpleQueryControl